# Finding $a,b,c$ using the equation provided

Tags: trigonometry

Provided with the equation

$$\sin^2 (n+1)x - \sin^2 (n-1)x = \sin2nx \sin2x$$

Find the values of $a,b,c$ if

$$ \sin^2 3x - \sin^2 x = 8\cos^2 x (a\cos^4 x + b\cos^2 x + c)$$

What I have tried

$(1 - \cos^2 3x)- (1- \cos^2 x)=8\cos^2 x (a\cos^4 x + b\cos^2 x + c)$

Expanding out the LHS

$(1 - (\cos 2x \cos x - \sin 2x \sin x )^2)  + \cos^2 x -1 $

$=( \cos x( 2\cos^2 x -1)-2\sin^2 x \cos x)^2$

$=\cos^2 x((2\cos^2x -1) -2(1-\cos^2 x))^2 $

$=\cos^2 x(4\cos^2 x -3)^2 $

$=16\cos^6 x -24\cos^4 x  + 9\cos^2 x$

By comparing,

$a=2$

$b=-3$

$c=\frac{9}{8}$

Is there a way to do the question using the equation they provided? I can't seem to see it.Any tips would be useful.Thank you!

Comment: Put n=2 and compare the RHS in first equation

Comment: Yes,I also tried that, doing that would give me $\sin 4x \sin 2x $ on the RHS of the original equation , which in the end I would still need to expand out painfully.

Comment: Well..It is not as painful as you think....Only a couple of steps yields the answer

Comment: Hmmm,seems like thats the fastest way... I kinda got stumped when they gave me $\cos x$ in the 2nd equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend, your answer is wrong,

Correct answer is  $a=-2$, $b=3$ and $c=-1$

For a quick verification, put $x=0$ ;
LHS = $0$
thus RHS must be $0$, i.e. $a+b+c=0$. Which isn't true in your case.

Proper proof using given equation :

$\sin^2(n+1)x−\sin^2(n−1)x=\sin2nx\sin2x$

Put $n=2$

$\sin^23x−\sin^2x= \sin4x\sin2x$

$= 2\sin^22x\cos2x$

$= 2(1-(2\cos^2x-1)^2)(2\cos^2x-1)$

$= 2(4\cos^2x-\cos^4x)(2\cos^2x-1)$

$= 8\cos^2x(1-\cos^2x)(2cos^2x-1)$

$= 8\cos^2x(-2\cos^4x+3\cos^2x-1)$

Thus ;

$a=-2$ ,

$b=3$ , and

$c=-1$

Comment: Oooo,thanks for telling me my mistake and I will correct it later.Thanks for the tip too.